# problem in dispatching to j_spring_security_check from managed bean in spring security?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, primefaces

I want to configure JSF (primefaces) with spring but i have a problem in using spring security.
for some reason (checking captcha later) i dispatch to "j_spring_security_check" from managedbean, after inserting the username and password and so on and submitting the request the method of the managedbean is called and then blow error message is appread in console and so authentication is failed:

**Feb 01, 2020 5:29:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound**

**WARNING: No mapping for POST /common/form/j_spring_security_check**

**Feb 1, 2020 5:29:06,156 PM IRST   Warning   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound BEA-000000 No mapping for POST /common/form/j_spring_security_check**

anyone can help what should i do to solve this problem (preferred java config)? thank you.

login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Login</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="loginFormId" prependId="false">

        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-fluid center ui-noborder">
            <h2>Please login</h2>

            <p:outputLabel value="Login failed!" styleClass="red"
                           rendered="${!empty param['error']}" />

            <p:inputText id="username" placeholder="User name" />
            <p:password id="password" placeholder="Password" />

            <p:commandButton value="Login" ajax="false" action="#{loginCtrl.login}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

WebInitializer.java

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "mcom")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mcom.*"})
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:mcom/m2/common/config/Application.properties")
public class WebConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource(){
        System.out.println("WebConfig.dataSource");

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource){
        System.out.println("WebConfig.entityManagerFactoryBean");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("mcom");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        System.out.println("WebConfig.transactionManager");

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
```

SecurityInitializer.java

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SecurityConfig.configureGlobal");

        try {
            builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("kobe")
                    .password("{noop}1234").roles("USER").and()
                    .withUser("james").password("{noop}1414").roles("ADMIN", "USER");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("SecurityConfig.configure");

        try {
            http.addFilterBefore(new customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**","/form/login.xhtml").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/form/login.xhtml").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/form/home.xhtml").failureUrl("/form/login.xhtml?error=true");
            http.csrf().disable();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginCtrl.java

```
try {
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest)context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("j_spring_security_check");
            dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: I don't see any jsf related code in here besides some config. And retrieving an HttpServletRequest from the FacesContext

Comment: @kukeltje, i used primefaces taglibs in the xhtml login form! Do you know the answer, please?!

Comment: there is **nothing** PrimeFaces related in the question.. And no I don't know the answer since I don't use spring (never did, never will)

Comment: It is even worse... the page you try to call (or Spring does) is not mapped as being processed by jsf. I doubt there is anything jsf related in the stacktrace

Comment: So if you remove the `p:panelgrid` and change the input, button etc to plain jsf `h:` ones it works? If not, it is not PrimeFaces related.